# When I run "node-gyp build" for a cpp package that simulates a native click I get a v8 error

Tags: python, c++, node.js, npm

When I run "node-gyp build" for a cpp package that simulates a native windows app I get an error related to deprecated v8 functions. I tried all the fixes suggested on the node-gyp page and none of them work. Anyone had similar issues?

Do you have any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

This is the github for the source:
https://github.com/fireveined/node-simulate-native-click

node-gyp rebuild

```
main.cpp

win_delay_load_hook.cc
```

C:\Automation\Emails\main.cpp(14,50): error C2660: 'v8::Value::NumberValue': function does not take 0 arguments [C:\Automation\Emails\build\addon.vcxproj]

Comment: the code is 3 years old, the V8 API isn't very stable, it probably simply isn't compatible with the current version of node.

Comment: Post needed code here, a [mcve].